# d3 date parsing chooses different timezones

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, d3.js

Trying to parse a date string using d3 and it seems to give me dates in EST before March 10th 2013 and datetimes in EDT after March 11th 2013. Can I choose which timezone it returns in? Or how can I get a consistent format?

```
x1 = '2013-03-10'
x2 = '2013-03-11'
parse_date = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse
console.log(parse_date(x1)) // Returns Sun Mar 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
console.log(parse_date(x2)) // Returns Mon Mar 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Comment: The documentation is here: [*Time Formatting*](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#parse). You can append "Z" to the string and format `"%Y-%m-%dZ"` to use UTC, or  `"%Y-%m-%d%z"` and append a particular offset.

Comment: Hmm appending 'Z' to the string `'2013-03-10Z'` and to `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dZ")` doesn't seem to have any effect.